# callback при шаринге vk

Tags: vkontakte-api

Возникла необходимость проверять, разместил ли пользователь запись на стене. Можно это без проблем делать через виджет указав callback функцию, но у нас кастомный дизайн кнопки поэтому мы используем обычный шаринг через ссылку. При этом никаких callback там само собой нету.

Подскажите подалуйста есть ли возможность сохранив кастомную кнопку, отследить факт размещения публикации?

Comment: Привязать на нее кастомную кнопку, а саму кастомную скрыть. или сделать отдельное событие.

Comment: Если расскажете чуть подробнее будет очень здорово, пока если честно не понял. Пробовали сделать кастомную кнопку и по нажатию на нее эмулировать нажатие на скрытую кнопку контакта, но там iframe и получить доступ к элементам внутри iframe нереально

Comment: Давно уже это делал, все прям в точности не помню как было, но помню, что привязки по событию делал отдельно от кастома. Хотя с другой стороны кастом можно визуально изменить, а из iframe можно подтянуть инфу из js и тульнуть на страничку во временный DOM, а потом распарсить, что нужно и как нужно.